# Do same thing onclick and click outside an element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I do have 3 elements with same class on my page and when you click on which one it should change the opacity of some images, have animation towards and backwards and hide 2 other elements etc. Also when you click outside them it should do the same thing.

What i've got so far is, It works fine but i don't know how to get it works when you click again on the same class element but it works fine when you click outside.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var tipClick = $('.tip');
      var dId  = $(tipClick).attr('data-id');
      var activeTip = $('.tip.active').attr('data-id');
      $(tipClick).on('click', function(e){
          $("#homepage .homepage-cnt.l .main.img .m").toggleClass("op").fadeTo( 0, 0.2 );
          $(".main.img").toggleClass(dId);
          $(this).toggleClass('active');
          $(".clone .n").show();
          $(".tip i svg").css({
              '-webkit-animation' : 'spin .3s forwards',
                 '-moz-animation' : 'spin .3s forwards',  
                  'animation'     : 'spin .3s forwards'
          });
          e.preventDefault();
        }); 
      $(document).click(function(){
          $("#homepage .homepage-cnt.l .main.img .m").removeClass('op').fadeTo( 1000, 1 );
          $(".clone .n").hide();
          $(".clone").removeClass("art-t-r");
          $(".clone").removeClass("art-m-l");
          $(".clone").removeClass("art-b-l");
          $(".tip.t-r").fadeIn(500);
          $(".tip.m-l").fadeIn(500);
          $(".tip.b-l").fadeIn(500);
          $(".art").fadeOut(100);
          $(".tip i svg").css({
              '-webkit-animation' : 'spinback .3s backwards',
                 '-moz-animation' : 'spinback .3s backwards',  
                  'animation'     : 'spinback .3s backwards'
          });
      });
  });
```

I totally stuck there, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post some html too bob..

Comment: create a http://jsfiddle.net/ please...